# PHP acting strange when trying to run Wordpress on LAMP server

Tags: php, wordpress

hello!

```
Ubuntu Trusty
PHP5, Apache2, mySQL installed
```

Download and unpack Wordpress to /var/www/html

Setup mySQL database and user for Wordpress, edit Wordpress config w/ correct info

In browser,

```
website.com/index.php is blank
website.com/readme.html works fine, points me to /wp-admin/install.php
webstie.com/wp-admin/install.php gives the classic error 
          "Error: PHP is not running"
```

Huh, this is strange. I purge and reinstall php5 and apache2, same error.

I create /var/www/html/info.php with

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

and it works fine, even tells me that mySQL is working

Okay, so in SSH I run

```
rm /var/www/html/index.php
nano ./index.php
```

and I copy the same code from info.php and **the page is blank?**

I am at the end of my abilities and patience with this issue, any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The output of **phpinfo** will include the path to the php.ini file currently in use. It contains all of PHP's settings.

Change this line in php.ini:

```
display_errors = off
```

to

```
display_errors = on
```

Then see if those "blank" pages give you an error message to work with.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the tutorial that I followed](http://www.ubuntuboss.com/how-to-install-wordpress-ubuntu-14-04-03/) and it works great so far it shows all the steps to configure all of the dependencies. What version of ubuntu are you using? ps: if php is not installed run sudo apt-get install php5 and WordPress requires php5-mysql package so run sudo apt-get install php5-mysql as well